# How to make RTE hyperlinks "Open in new window" by default in adobe cq5?

Tags: javascript, adobe, aem

I'm trying to modify LinkDialog.js under RTE to have the checkbox "Open in a new window" checked by default. According to the day API, it should just be adding the value "checked": true to the default values, but that doesn't work. It does accept my other value changes, such as the name, so I now the edits are coming through.

Here's the code I modified:

```
{
                "itemId": "targetBlank",
                "name": "targetBlank",
                "xtype": "checkbox",
                "boxLabel": CQ.I18n.getMessage("Open in new window"),
                "checked": true,
                "value": "targetBlank"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these props:

```
checked="{Boolean}true"
defaultValue="true"
```

Comment: Check out this question--seems like perhaps a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483546/getting-default-checked-checkbox-in-cq5  Essentially says   defaultValue (String) true
fieldLabel (String) Foo Mode  
inputValue (String) false  
jcr:primaryType (Name) cq:Widget  
name (String) ./foomode  
type (String) checkbox  
xtype (String) selection