# Select value from xtype selection type checkbox CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem

Hello I am running an issue right now. I would like to make the checkbox state: checked but I could not make the defaultValue="value"

```
<channels jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Channels"
                defaultValue="Value" name="channels" options="/bin/sample/private/getJSON.json"
                 optionsValueField="Value" type="checkbox" xtype="selection">
```

I have tried to do this: [Getting Default Checked Checkbox in CQ5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483546/getting-default-checked-checkbox-in-cq5)

but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: What does `/bin/sample/private/getJSON.json` return?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of what I have used to set the default state of the checkbox as 'checked'. Take note of `defaultValue="true"`

```
<channels
   jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
   fieldLabel="Channels"
   name="channels"
   type="checkbox"
   defaultValue="true"
   xtype="selection"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it this way.

```
<channels jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
          fieldLabel="Channels"
          defaultValue="{Boolean}true" 
          name="channels" options="/bin/sample/private/getJSON.json"
          optionsValueField="Value" 
          type="checkbox" 
          xtype="selection">
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue you refer to is to create the checkbox using js / json.
if you look at what is actually getting stored in the JCR you will see that the value against a checkbox is not actually a boolean, but is a string. which can be true / flase, or on / off if the item is inside a checkboxgroup.

In your case, to make it automatically checked in your dialog.xml file you need to use checked="true".